# Strange memory issue - Is it the motherboard instead?

Tags: memory, hardware-failure

My desktop system has started experiencing random BSOD crashes in the
past 2 weeks.

There is no pattern to the crashes, each one is a different stop code,
in a different kernel module, which to me points to memory problems.

I ran Memtest86 and it comes up with *THOUSANDS* of errors, in a specific
range of locations between `0x150000000` and `0x170000000` (i.e. between
5376MB and 5888MB).

The error bit pattern is always `0x00240000`, meaning the discrepancy
between what is written and what is read back is always in those two
bits only.  Also, it's not a stuck bit, as the discrepancy at either bit
position is a flipped bit, not always the same value.  As an example, in
one error the written pattern is `0x80808080` but what is read back is
`0x80848080` (a zero-bit flipped to one), but when the pattern is
`0x7F7F7F7F` the read value is `0x7F7B7F7F` (a one-bit flipped to zero).

*If I remove one module and test each module by itself, Memtest86 reports
ZERO errors.*

If I put both modules in, the error address range is the same regardless
of which way the modules are inserted. I.e. if I swap them the error
address range does not change.

The motherboard has 4 memory slots labeled A1, A2, B1, B2.  The manual recommends that when using 2 modules you use A2/B2.  I also tried using A1/B1 but this resulted in exactly the same error address range.

Given:

1. The modules individually test OK
2. The failing address range does not change when I swap the modules
3. The failing address range does not change when I use the alternate memory slots

This sounds awfully like the problem is "upstream" from the memory sockets and modules themselves, and my motherboard is toast.

**Question**: Is there another possible explanation for this, and are there any other diagnostic steps I can take to pinpoint where the problem is?

Some details in case they're needed:

- **Motherboard**: ASUS Z97-WS, in service flawlessly since 2014/09 up to now
- **Memory**: 2 Kingston KHX1866C10D3/8G (on the ASUS compatibility list)
- **CPU**: Intel Core i7-4790K @ 4.00 GHz (not overclocked)

Comment: I’ve seen multiple times where bad RAM will not show up until it is used with other RAM. Memtest is by no means guaranteed accurate.  I’ve seen, at least once, this exact same problem and a simple BIOS update fixed it. So, MemTest can not be your sole source of truth in this situation. Your best bet is to fully use your system with each module, and see if you can identify an unstable system with one of the modules. Memtest may take 24 hours or longer to actually find an error also.

Comment: Do you have the means to repair the motherboard? If the answer is "no", then the only option is to replace it; isn't that so? Having the schematic: Is there any circuitry transferring data to the CPU, then that circuitry is the first suspect (read datasheet) after the MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue turned out to be one of the two 8GB memory sticks.

The ambiguity came from the fact that it displayed errors only when running in dual-channel mode, i.e. only when both sticks were in the system.  When each stick was installed by itself in the motherboard no errors were reported.

I decided that I wanted to increase the memory in my system anyway, so I bought an additional 16GB.  If one stick was bad I'd end up with 24GB, and if it was the motherboard I would end up with 32GB (after a painful system rebuild).

After installing the new 16GB I tried the two old sticks one at a time.  One immediately produced errors, and the other went through several complete passes of Memtest86 without error.

Conclusion: One 8gb stick had developed errors.  I avoided a MB replacement and system rebuild, and am now a happy camper with 24GB, enough to do some really large panoramas in Lightroom :-)

Edit: Found out the memory has a lifetime warranty (Kingston) and have shipped it back for a replacement.  I'll have 32GB after all :-)